# bootstrap modal opacity changing to white

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap and when I try to set the .modal and .modal-header background colours the default opacity where you can see the website behind the modal changes to white.  I want to keep the opacity as default and only change the modal and modal header colours.  This is the code I am using:

```
.modal {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size:16px;

  }

.modal-header {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size:24px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of .modal you should work on .modal-content and .modal-header

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size:16px;

}

.modal-header {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size:24px;
 }
```

Comment: this works but now the curved corners at the top of the modal are gone

Comment: Edited the answer. Add border radius to header.